# What is the relationship between Steppenwolf and Darkseid in the DC Extended Universe?

Tags: character, dc-extended-universe, comic-adaptation, justice-league

In the DC comics, Steppenwolf is the uncle of Darkseid. However, their relation was not made clear in the *Justice League* (2017) movie. I've read many [CBR articles](https://www.cbr.com/), as well as several other sources, several of which contradict each other about it. A few claimed that their relation is the same as it is in the comics, and a few claim that it's just the opposite. Did they ever clarify their relationship in an extended medium from canon or in an interview?

<sub>Note: I'm aware of a similar [question on Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/174621/what-is-the-relationship-between-steppenwolf-and-darkseid), which didn't get a satisfactory answer for my question.</sub>

Comment: Comparing Darkseid and Steppenwolf, Darkseid is more powerful right? So if they choose to bring Darkseid to DCEU, it'd be boring as hell. It took whole movie to others even hit Steppenwolf, until superman gets there. So superman getting his ass kicked by Darkseid would make the movie very dull,

Comment: @Vishwa Even in Comics both of them are this strong, If I am not wrong one version of Steppenwolf even killed wonder woman in comics

Answer (score 2):

### Steppenwolf is Darkseid's uncle according to Director Zack Snyder.

In the following junket interview via comicbook.com with Director Zack Snyder for the release of *Zack Snyder's Justice League*, at 5:00 he says:

> The big arc is Darkseid. . . so he literally sends his . . . Uncle Steppenwolf to Earth

Source: